# Why the Microsoft Pay window is empty?

Tags: c#, uwp

My task is to configure the payment system for the UWP application. I use the information from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/payment-request).

I ran the example for the first time, and it worked. Then I logged into my account, filled in the payment details and clicked the Buy button. But now the Microsoft Pay window [opens blank](https://monosnap.com/file/lb8ZlLCZTUSRavM6HZ5ZgmAe3dqMNj). I used a test project from GitHub and the code above. My Microsoft Pay window works fine in the Microsoft store.

I did not change anything in their code, there is no exception. I have no idea where to look for the cause of this problem.

**UPD**:
[JSON of my PaymentRequest](https://anotepad.com/notes/65ykp4rm)

> var request = new PaymentRequest(details, acceptedPaymentMethods, merchantInfo, options, "1");

Comment: I'm sorry to say it's unclear why it happens. Do you get any error or exception in the code？

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, I don't have any exeption in the my code. I added JSON of my PaymentRequest above maybe this will help.

Comment: Check the "Onboarding requirements" and "Geos and locations" sections at the bottom of [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/03/28/simplify-payments-uwp-apps-payment-request-api-microsoft/).

Comment: My company has US registration.
This page has been around for three years now, I guess this API is supported by most regions.
I have DEV account and I thought Seller ID = merchantId. Now I understand that I need to register in the Seller Center as a seller.
On the [page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/payments/merchants#primaryR7), I click on "Connect your merchant account" and get an [error](https://monosnap.com/file/ddFzqzRNOGKmg1dGWTKDwktBvgJCAQ). I sent an error report. Maybe there is another way?

Comment: It’s still strange why once my Microsoft Pay window worked ..

Comment: Ok, it seems that you've found the root cause. But it's still a problem that you can't register in the Seller Center as a seller, This is related to the Dashboard according to your screenshot. Does the page work correctly when you are using another browser?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Yes, the behavior in other browsers is identical. I tested Opera, IE and Chrome.
I think I need to write to developers about this problem. I don’t close the question yet, then I’ll add a solution, maybe someone will come in handy.

Comment: [500 $ ?. That's cool.](https://monosnap.com/file/coXfssh0KUqJnHI37WHmq3BPMcfv8I) I have a problem due to their bug. And I have to pay them to find out the solution. Is there a cheap way to get an answer from them?

Comment: May I know why you need to add json when you are opening a pay window that you don't need to interact with programmatically.

Comment: It was generated from a variable of type PaymentRequest using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to show what is in my first parameter for `paymentMediator.SubmitPaymentRequestAsync`. This all happens when the payment window is called up, then I just wait for the callback.

Comment: I am ready to pay for help in solving my problem. I will give the necessary access. Write to vlad.s@panther.vegas or better in Telegram https://t.me/Vlad777333
Perhaps the problem is on my side.

Comment: Have you tried to add the same JSON string into the official sample to check if the sample works correctly? Or the test result you told me already contains it? And what if you don't add the JSON string, will the error still happen in your app? I just want to confirm if the error might be related to the JSON string.

Comment: I almost did not change anything in their example. Here is the part of the code where the request is already being generated, so that it is clear where I get the JSON.
https://monosnap.com/file/8yeH5D4UuVSGrvrl30xDtYUSxellvb
There are only two overloads in the SubmitPaymentRequestAsync method. Requests required https://monosnap.com/file/82bUCQVyFxvAfnWLq3FMKPxAyinrSB

Comment: In the beginning, I thought you added the JSON string into the request and that's why I'm asking. After checking your screenshot, it seems I misunderstand it. The code you are using looks correct. Could you please open a free support ticket here:[Contact Us](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support). Choose to Contact us, select Dashboard for Topic and select In-app purchases for issue type.